# Music glossaries online

Tags: discussion

For non-English speakers, technical terms about music are sometimes difficult to find.

Can you list available glossaries please?

I will start with the [musical notation glossary](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.12/Documentation/user/music-glossary/index.html) from LilyPond.

Comment: +1 I think Meta is probably a good place to have this sort of reference.  Maybe http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/175/violin-fingering-schemes-for-different-scales should be moved here.

Comment: It can be part of the FAQ.

Comment: In bikes.SE they have a big question with one answer per term, which I think is really handy. Of course it should be linked from the FAQ.
See http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index

Comment: @Ign - It *is* linked from [our FAQ](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/faq). And thanks!